Combine Azure assessments with subassessments
I have two kql queries that I'd like to see about combining if possible.  There are some assessments that have a subassessment associated with it, such as "Machines should be configured securely".  with the second query I can pull but I'd like to be able to combine the two so I could sort in one excel and display the Subscription name and not the ID.  I have tried but don't seem to understand the join well enough to succeed.  Does anyone have a kql script that provides the desired output?
//Get the subscription name but like to have the associated subassessments available.
securityresources 
| where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments' 
| join kind=leftouter  (resourcecontainers 
            | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
            | project subscriptionId, subscription=name)
        on subscriptionId
| extend resourceId = tolower(tostring(properties.resourceDetails.ResourceId))
| join kind=leftouter  (resources | project resourceId=tolower(id), rtags=tags.SystemID, resourceName=name) on resourceId
| project 
    subscription,
    resourceGroup,
    resourceName,
    resourceType=tostring(properties.resourceDetails.ResourceType), 
    SystemID=rtags,
    recommendationSeverity=properties.metadata.severity, 
    recommendationStatus =properties.status.code,
    recommendationName=properties.displayName, 
    description=properties.metadata.description, 
    remediationDescription=properties.metadata.remediationDescription,    
    portalLink=properties.links.azurePortal,
    resourceId

//will give you all the associated issues with the main assessments but not the subscription name.
securityresources
| where type == "microsoft.security/assessments"
| summarize by assessmentKey=name //the ID of the assessment
| join kind=inner (
   securityresources
    | where type == "microsoft.security/assessments/subassessments"
    | extend assessmentKey = extract(".*assessments/(.+?)/.*",1,  id)
) on assessmentKey
| project assessmentKey, subassessmentKey=name, id, parse_json(properties), resourceGroup, subscriptionId, tenantId
| extend description = properties.description,
        displayName = properties.displayName,
        resourcename= parse_json(properties.resourceDetails),
        resourceId = properties.resourceDetails.id,
        resourceSource = properties.resourceDetails.source,
        //category = properties.category,
        severity = properties.status.severity,
        //code = properties.status.code,
        timeGenerated = properties.timeGenerated,
        remediation = properties.remediation,
        impact = properties.impact,
        vulnId = properties.id,
        additionalData = properties.additionalData      
   | project assessmentKey, subassessmentKey, subscriptionId, vulnId, displayName, resourcename, resourceId,severity, remediation, impact


Can you provide your sample input and expected output?
